# Как сравнить значение поля сейчас с тем что было 10 секунд назад?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть столбец.
беру оттуда значение(значение от 1 до 100):

```
var a = $('td').eq(11).children().val();
```

Это значение меняется. Как проверять Нынешнее значение равно ли предыдущему?

Comment: нужно сохранить значение в переменную, а через 10 секунд проверить текущей значение со значением сохраненной переменной

Comment: @Grundy  Я так и планирую  только незнаю как быть .Создаю 1 интевл внутри него сохраняю переменную и там же создаю ещё интеервал?немог бы пример показать такого рода

Comment: а второй интервал зачем?

Comment: @Grundy  пример бы мне очень помог .Я чето немогу понять.А как мне нынешнее значение сравнить с тем что было 10 сек назад

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начальное значение ты уже сохранил

```
var prev = $('td').eq(11).children().val();
```

Осталось запустить таймер и сравнить текущее значение с предыдущим

```
setInterval(function(){ // возможно тут хватит setTimeout, если надо сравнить один раз
    var current =  $('td').eq(11).children().val(); // получаем текущее значение
    if(current == prev){...} // сравниваем значение и выполняем необходимые действия
    prev = current; // сохраняем текущее значение, для сравнения на следующей итерации
}, timeout)
```

Comment: АААААА устал у походу .Я не сохранял текущее сравние для следующией итерации